# Test-Driven Development (TDD) using Xamarin and StackMob?

Tags: android, tdd, stackmob

I am interested in using StackMob as my BeAAS on a project using Xamarin to create an Android and IOS version of my mobile app. I am using the StackMob.NET solution from

https://github.com/ermau/StackMob.NET.

I was successful at running the demo from the Android emulator however, I am unable to make successful contact to StackMob via NUnit (Visual Studio or Xamarin Suite).

Is this because I am not attempting a connection from within a mobile View? Or is it possible to create test methods that can connect to StackMob?

Also, has anyone tried integrating StackMob with Xamarin or .Net?

Comment: Are you trying to use OAuth v1 or v2 with it? The v2 support is incomplete.

Comment: I was using OAuth v2 similar to the Android sample you had. Have you been able to integrate you library into a xamarin project for either Android or IOS?

Comment: As I said, the OAuth v2 support is incomplete. To be more specific, it's not going to work at all. You'll need to use v1 to get successful calls.

Given that there's a Android sample that you yourself is working, I'd say that's able to integrate into a xamarin project for Android.